# Grep text only only after [word]:

Tags: grep

I have a file `example.txt` which contains following text:

```
[one]: bla bla bla onebla twobla
[two]: hey heya noheya
[onemore]: i got mad and etc
```

I need to grep and show only text that after `[myword]`:
Tried to test it this way:

```
grep [myword] /tmp/example.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

On each `[myword]` it prints all after brackets, but how can I get only the one I need only and not all?

I need to print only the test that after certain brackets. For example I want to print only text that in line `[one]:`  but not after `[two]:` or `[onemore]:`lines, so that the output will be `bla bla bla onebla twobla`. If I want to print all after `[onemore]:` - the correct output should be `i got mad and etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish the solution which is independent on a delimiter, the use `awk`

```
$ cat 304162 
[one]: bla bla bla onebla twobla
[two]: hey heya noheya
[onemore]: i got mad and etc
[fourth:one]: some more bla, well ! worst case
$ awk '/\[onemore\]/{sub(/^[^]]*\]:[[:blank:]]*/,"");print}' 304162
i got mad and etc
$ awk '/\[fourth:one\]/{sub(/^[^]]*\]:[[:blank:]]*/,"");print}' 304162
some more bla, well ! worst case
```

Answer (score 3):

Better with `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^\[one]: //p' < example.txt
```

With GNU `grep` with support for recent PCRE, you can also do:

```
grep -Po '^\[one]: \K.*' < example.txt
```

Or

```
grep -xPo '\[one]: \K.*' < example.txt
```

In any case, note that in most shells, `[...]` are glob operators. In `grep [myword]`, `[myword]` is expanded to the list of files that match that, that is any file in the current directory whose name is `m`, `y`, `w`, `o`, `r` or `d` (and if there's none, depending on the shell, the pattern is passed as-is to `grep`, or you get an error). So they must be quoted for the shell (with single quotes for instance as in the solutions here). For instance, if there's a file called `r` in the current directory, and one called `d`, `grep [myword]` would become `grep d r` in all shells but `fish`.

`[...]` is *also* a special operator in regular expressions (very similar to the `[...]` glob operator), `grep '[myword]'` would match on lines that contain `m`, `y`, `w`, `o`, `r` or `d`. So you need to escape the opening `[` for `grep` (for regular expressions) as well. That can be done with `grep '\[myword]'` or `grep '[[]myword]'`.

`^` is another regular expression operator that means: match at the beginning of the line only. So `grep '^\[myword]: '` matches on lines that start with `[myword]:`.

While `grep` is just meant to print matching lines (is not otherwise a stream editor like `sed` is), GNU `grep` added the non-standard `-o` option for it to print the matching portion(s) of the line (if non-empty). It also added the `-P` options to use perl compatible regular expressions (in PCRE) instead of basic ones without `-P`.

In recent PCREs, `\K` is an operator that *resets* the start of the matching portion. So in `grep -Po '^\[one]: \K.*'`, we do print the matching portion because of `-o`, but because of `\K`, that matching portion becomes the sequence of characters (`.*`) that is found after `[one]:`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt give me any output (also where I should point to files to search in?)

Comment: @alya, see edit. It works for me on your sample. As stated, the `grep` one will not work on all systems, as it uses GNU extensions (so will only work on systems where `grep` is the GNU one (see `grep --version`) or have copied those extensions from GNU `grep`), and also the PCREs are relatively recent (`\K` was added only a few years ago).

Answer (score 0):

`[one]` regular expression means "a character matching `o` or `n` or `e`.
`grep [one] /tmp/example.txt`  will match all the lines of your example

To match the `[]` as characters you need to escape them :

```
grep \\[one\\] /tmp/example.txt   | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Or you can use `grep -F` which ignore the regular expression syntax :

```
grep -F [one] /tmp/example.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2
```